# Multiple end effectors in MoveIt!

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With MoveIt!, I'm trying to switch between two end effectors for a single arm. The purpose is to have 1 camera end effector and 1 gripper end effector. Is this what the MoveGroup setEndEffector() method was designed to do? Has anybody tried this before?

I know that somebody else in our lab is doing .setEndEffector() when the URDF contains two arms and he wants to switch between arms. Maybe that's the intended functionality.

Would it be possible, as a workaround, to have a completely separate planning group for the second end-effector? Most of the joints would be duplicated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264769/multiple-end-effectors-in-moveit!/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2017-06-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-26**:\

> Would it be possible, as a workaround, to have a completely separate planning group for the second end-effector?

yes. You can have as many groups as you want. This is often used with IKFast plugins fi where special plugins are generated for specific robot+tool combos.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-06-26**:
Do I need to destroy previous moveGroup instances before creating a new one?

Currently, if I create a second moveGroup and plan a motion, the terminal output from my executable is `Aborted: Catastrophic Failure`. The output from moveIt is `Unable to construct goal representation.`

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-06-26**:
OK, I found out that the Catastrophic Failure was caused by incorrectly using moveit_setup_assistant. I wasn't overwriting some of the files where manual editing was detected. Would still like to know if it's possible to use more than 1 EE per kinematic chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey AndyZe,

the use-case you describe (camera, gripper) is how I would use `getEndEffector` too.
Multiple end-effectors per group are clearly the intended idea of this part of the code.
You filed https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/522 rather recently,
and I don't think it's unlikely that there is a bug in the code for some use-cases.

For the use-case with two arms, this is only a reasonable way forward if you need to plan for both arms to move simultaneously. Otherwise it is computationally more easy to use two different planning groups and MoveGroup instances instead.

Maybe you miss a call to `clearPoseTargets()` in between your different planning requests?

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-06-27**:
`clearPoseTargets()` could be it. Thanks! I will certainly close the github issue if I find a solution. In a way, multiple EE's for one arm doesn't make sense because there can only be 1 kinematic chain.

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-06-27**:
if you find a solution, please explain your solution in the issue :)
Maybe we can add code to point the issue out to the next user running into this.

> there can only be 1 kinematic chain

wrong. you can model arbitrary joint sets as group.
Also you can have a group of multiple subgroups.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-06-27**:
Ok, thanks. I mean, you can probably do this:

```
Arm---EE1---EE2
```

But not:

```
Arm----- EE1
     |
     |--------------EE2
```

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-06-27**:
You *can* create this construct, the datastructures in MoveIt as well as the Planner should support it. At the moment inverse kinematics is usually the impasse for practical applications.